# Some questions about MS Gvim

Tags: vim

I am a MS Gvim user and I have some questions about MS Gvim.I hope that I can get answers from here. Thanks all of you in advance.

1.How is the Gvim on windows version developed?Using Visual Studio or Qt?how can I get the source code?

2.When I have installed the Gvim ,I will have a directory in C:\Program Files(x86)\Vim.

In Vim directory, there are two directories and a file: (1)vim74 (2)vimfiles (3)_vimrc
  I just wonder what the two directories represent and how it is used when I start my Gvim.

3.Can vimscript be called a language? How is it compiled or interpreted?

Answer (score 3):

#### Development and source code

The latest source code and runtime files can be downloaded via FTP or retrieved from Mercurial; see [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/sources.php) for details. Using Mercurial is easiest:

```
hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
```

Vim can be compiled with various versions of the Visual Studio C++ compilers, see the corresponding Makefile in `src/Make_mvc.mak`. You don't need a full Visual Studio installation, the (free) compiler from the Windows SDK will do:

```
nmake -f Make_mvc.mak
```

Alternatively, you can use the [MinGW compiler](http://www.mingw.org) through `src/Make_ming.mak`.

GVIM uses the native Win32 widgets; Qt isn't used (on Unix, Gnome is the prevalent UI toolkit).

#### Vim installation structure

The Vim binaries and supporting files reside in the (versioned, so you can have multiple versions installed in parallel) `vim74` directory. `vimfiles` and `_vimrc` contain a default configuration. Note that it is recommended to do customizations to copies in your *home directory* instead. The whole process and which files are read (it's complex) is described under `:help startup`.

#### Vimscript

Yes, Vimscript is the language used for extending Vim and writing plugins (though a variety of other languages like Perl, Python, and Ruby can be integrated with Vim and then be invoked via a single Vimscript command).

It started as the set of *Ex commands* (`:delete`, `:substitute`, etc.) it inherited from vi, but also has built-in functions (e.g. `getbufvar()`, `system()`) and the ability to define custom functions and (primitive) objects. Since version 7.0, Vimscript has (Python-inspired) data structures like *List* and *Dictionary*, and is a fully-fledged, powerful (but still in some aspects somewhat quirky) language.

Comment: By "on Unix, Gnome is the prevalent UI toolkit", do you mean most gVim users on Unix use the official Gtk+ version? Or that Gtk+/GNOME is more common in general than Qt? (I believe there is a Unix Qt port of gVim, but it doesn't seem like people usually talk about it; but I haven't done enough outside of OS X these days to have an opinion on the popularity of Gtk+ vs. Qt.)

Comment: The Gnome version is in all the (Ubuntu, Debian, etc.) packages, so it's fair to call it the default. There used to be a `kvim` Qt-version, but I haven't heard anything about it for years. Only very few people still use the (ugly) Athena UI, I think